# WP7: How to make the same animation as the system when navigating pages

Tags: silverlight, animation, windows-phone-7

anyone knows the exact parameters of the animations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the *exact* values are, but you can get pretty close by looking at the source code for the [Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). For example, the [`SwivelForwardIn`](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61620#1349613) transition.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a wp7 machine. Does all apps have the similar style when animating? MS really should write something about it.

Comment: You don't need a WP7 device to see these animations in action; you can use the emulator that comes as part of the Windows Phone Developer Tools[1]. It is the responsibility of third party application developers to add page transition animations to their pages, but it is not a requirement.

 [1]: http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started